# JSON Datatype in not available in Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, json

JSON is not appears in datatypes of PHPMyAdmin. So, i install mysql community server installer 5.7.9 and connect to xampp mysql. but the problem appears when a row with json type added and table altered using mysql workbench. it shows error.
I think it is due to the version used by sql for this connection is old MySQL associated with Xampp and i need to attach the current loaded mysql version so JSON type supported or any other way if possible.

Can i install separate apache server or php or both and then connect them to currently installed mysql

Comment: Please post the error message

Comment: `json is not a datatype`..what is meant by json? ...check it out here http://json.org/

Comment: It sounds like your new mysql server is not linked to xampp. Read here to upgrade your existing xampp mysql server version: https://superuser.com/questions/566013/how-can-i-upgrade-the-mysql-version-included-in-xampp

Comment: Executing:
CREATE TABLE `shopstreat`.`new_table` (
  `idnew_table` INT NOT NULL,
  `new_tablecol` JSON NULL,
  `new_tablecol1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnew_table`));

Comment: Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NULL,
  `new_tablecol1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnew_table`))' at line 3
SQL Statement:
CREATE TABLE `shopstreat`.`new_table` (
  `idnew_table` INT NOT NULL,
  `new_tablecol` JSON NULL,
  `new_tablecol1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idnew_table`))